# ¿Por qué no puedo iniciar sesión gráficamente en linux con un usuario creado desde la terminal?

Tags: linux, terminal, línea-de-comandos, cuenta-usuario, redirección

estoy estudiando la administración de usuarios en linux, ya sé crear usuarios y eso con el comando 'useradd', y de hecho cuando los creo solo usando `useradd usuario2` si puedo acceder gráficamente a la cuenta, mi duda viene del momento cuando quiero asignarle otra carpeta home que no es la default al nuevo usuario, para eso creé otra carpeta en la raíz a la que le puse home2 nada más para ver si podía crear un usuario con la carpeta home distinta a la que es por defecto. Lo que en terminal sería:

```
cd /
```

y luego

```
mkdir /home2/usuario2
```

ahora cuando quiero crear el nuevo usuario lo escribo así:

```
useradd -d /home2/usuario2 -u 802 -g 1000 -c usr2 usuario2
```

Por lo que tengo entendido -d sirve para asignarle un directorio home en específico, así que no sé si está bien ahí por que también sé que se puede usar -b, pero no estoy seguro como se usa.
Bueno una vez que se crea el usuario le pongo la contraseña con:

```
sudo passwd usuario2
```

Después copio los archivos que están en /etc/skel a la carpeta home que le establecí al usuario2 usando el comando:

```
cp -r -/etc/skel /home2/usuario2
```

Y ya con esto creo se tiene todo listo para iniciar sesión gráficamente pero cuando lo intento solo me aparece una pantalla negra y luego regresa a la pantalla de login de usuarios.

Ahora esto que mencioné antes no me pasa cuando uso -m al crear el usuario, e incluso cuando yo mismo creo la carpeta del usuario en home y le copio los archivos que están en /etc/skel, solo así es cuando si puedo entrar gráficamente.

Answer (score 1):

Supongo que eso tiene que ver con el tipo de servidor de pantalla que tengas y su configuración. Tal vez se sirve de la existencia de un directorio base específico (`/home` y no `/home2`).

Si quieres ver lo que sucede específicamente en tu caso podrías apretar ctrl + alt + f1 o f2, para iniciar sin modo gráfico, registrarte y luego ingresar `tail /var/log/syslog`.

La solución será dependiendo de la distribución que tengas y el servidor de pantalla o de ventanas. Por ejemplo, a veces sirve hacer esto:

```
sudo systemctl restart gdm.service
```

### Aclaraciones.

Para crear la carpeta, puedes utilizar el parámetro `-m` de `useradd`, es decir, te puede quedar algo así (como bien explicaste, sólo que lo añado al cuerpo):

```
useradd -md /home2/usuario2 -u 802 -g 1000 -c usr2 usuario2
```

Lo que hace esto es que, sin el parámetro `-k`, el directorio esqueleto (suena gracioso) estará definido en la variable `SKEL` dentro del archivo `/etc/default/useradd`, o será por defecto `/etc/skel`. Como esa carpeta será la que se copiará dentro del home del nuevo usuario, tendrá que usarse por fuerza con el parámetro `-m` para que lo cree.

Por otro lado, para aclarar lo del parámetro `-k`, por ejemplo, que tienes un directorio personalizado que quieres usar como esqueleto:

```
/tmp/skel_niños/
|
|_ juguetes
|_ tareas
|_ cuentos de Perrault
|_ Rootkits y troyanos
|_ directorio_de_la_escuela
     |
     |_ calificaciones
     |_ exámenes
|_ otro-directorio
|_ .ssh/
     |_ ...
```

Entonces puedes usar:

```
sudo useradd \
-md /home2/niño1 \
-k /tmp/skel_niños \
-u 802 \
-g 1000 \
-c "niño1" \
niño1
```

Y cuando hagas un `ls -la` a `/home2/niño1` verás el contenido copiado de `/tmp/skel_niños`. Es decir, con la opción `-k /directorio/esqueleto` ya no tienes que copiarlo.

Lo que hace el parámetro `-b` es que cambia el directorio base. Por ejemplo, si tienes una carpeta llamada `/mnt/usuarios`, con el parámetro `-b /mnt/usuarios` y el parámetro `-m`, se creará una carpeta llamada `/mnt/usuarios/usuario1` (en caso de que hayas puesto de nombre "usuario1").

Entonces, ya con el parámetro `-b` puedes prescindir un poco de `-d`:

```
sudo useradd \
-mb /mnt/usuarios \
-k /tmp/skel_personalizado\
-u 802 \
-g 1000 \
-c nuevo_usuario1 \
usuario1
```

Y tendrás una carpeta llamada `usuario1` dentro de `/mnt/usuarios` con el contenido de `/tmp/skel_personalizado`.

Comment: Excelente respuuesta, Cuauhtli. La mía, más pobre, sólo hace que complementar la tuya. Supongo que estábamos editando al mismo tiempo. Saludos.

Comment: Gracias. Creo que tienes razón respecto a editar al mismo tiempo. Como sea, creo que las dos son útiles.

Answer (score 1):

El comando useradd efectivamente se usa para crear usuarios en entornos GNU/Linux. Es mucho más cómodo, por ser interactivo, el comando adduser, que te va guiando a través de diversas opciones:

```
adduser nombre.usuario
```

En cualquier caso, por resolver tus dudas:
Dentro del directorio home es donde se deben crear los directorios de los usuarios. No entiendo porqué has creado un home2:

```
home/usuario1
home/usuario2
```

etc.

Sería conveniente que comparases los permisos de uno y otro directorio, porque tampoco explicas cómo has creado home2

```
ls -dl /home/
drwxr-xr-x 5 root root 4096 jun  8  2018 /home/
```

Una manera, creo, adecuada, para crear usuarios con useradd (seguro que habrá otras, el comando tiene muchas opciones) sería ésta:

```
useradd -d /home/nombre.usuario -m -s /bin/bash -G plugdev,netdev,audio,video,cdrom,haldaemon,power,scanner nombre.usuario
```

Lo explico por partes, aunque es conveniente revisar el man useradd:

```
-d /home/fulanito
```

El directorio al que apunta la opción -d será el de logueo por defecto del usuario en cuestión. El directorio no tiene por qué existir, pero no será creado con esta opción.

```
-m
```

Crea el directorio del usuario, si no existe. Además, copiará los directorios y ficheros de skeleton al directorio del usuario (tambíén pueden definirse esas opciones con -k).

```
-s /bin/bash
```

define la ruta de la shell por defecto para el usuario creado (en nuestro ejemplo bash, pero hay otras como zsh, por ejemplo).

```
-G grupo,grupo #Sin espacios
```

Lista los grupos suplementarios de los que el usuario será miembro. Para un vistazo a todos los grupos puedes listar el contenido del fichero /etc/groups. Yo soy usuario de Slackware/Linux, y configuro esos, pero otras distros pueden o no tener configurados esos u otros.

Dado que no he especificado la opción -g (que propone el grupo inicial del usuario), éste se creará en función de la variable USERGROUPS_ENAB contenida en /etc/login.defs. En general, ese grupo por defecto será users.

Recuerda, como bien haces, crear una contraseña robusta para ese usuario.

El directorio /etc/skel contiene varios ficheros que definen una configuración básica de comportamiento, de bash (.bash_profile o .bashrc) o de mapeado del teclado (.inputrc) siempre a nivel de consola. En gráfico son otros ficheros los afectados. Puedes copiar todos los ficheros en el directorio del usuario, o no, o puedes modificarlos al gusto si lo deseas. Suelen venir muy comentados, para comprender qué hace cada directiva.

Desconozco qué distro usas, y si skel contiene ficheros que puedan afectar al entorno gráfico, a vista de tu último párrafo. 
Suerte.

Comment: Referente a lo de el directorio home2, lo cree yo y le asigne los permisos de lectura, escritura y ejecución a usuario; Entiendo que los usuarios se crean en \home pero cuando leyendo por internet encontré que se podían crear usuarios con una carpeta home diferente a la default, y lo intente así ademas de intentar ingresar por GUI  y por terminal pero de pasa lo de la pantalla negra. Mi distro es Xubuntu